# AutoHotKey Doesn't Respond

Tags: autohotkey

When I enter a hotkey [any hotkey], AutoHotKey doesn't respond.  However, it will respond if I edit, save, and reload it.  After which, it will respond three or four times then I must go through the same process of editing, saving, and reloading it again.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the program 10 or more times.

Before it began to not respond, it would leave a space after each string. [I'm not sure if that is related to my problem or not.]

I am using Windows 7 and IE 10.  I reinstalled IE 8 and IE 9 to see if either would correct the problem.  The problem remained.

Thanks for whatever help you may provide.

Comment: first question. Just reloading the script doesn't work? Also do you have #Persisent at the top of your script?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Reloading the script doesn't work.  No, I do not have #Persisent at the top of the script.  I have had this problem for over a month.  Prior to that AutoHotKey worked well.

Comment: @AFH Please post your code.

Comment: "@AFH Please post your code. – Armin"  What code?

Comment: @AFH Your autohotkey script code.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand of what code you speak.  If you speak of codes that I use to run a string, none of my codes works.  To give an example, I may have a code as follows "::afh::.  Prior to my present problem, I had used this type code for more than 5 years without any problem.

Comment: @AFH Example of ahk code: http://dotmac.rationalmind.net/files/2008/11/autohotkey.ahk

Comment: Thanks Armin, Sorry I was so slow in understanding what codes you were speaking of. The following is an example of the format of my ahk codes I use,      ::nct::ncteam{tab}ax12laweiY ::nfz::The ability to show forth true team work. ::oi::013120013201 ::pc::339606141 ::pfz::J2982F2G

Answer (score 0):

## Me too

I have encountered this same type of problem. AutoHotKey loads my script and responds for a while, then after X number of times the script simply stops responding.

## Resolution

To resolve these types of problems I found that opening the debug screen (double click the AutoHotKey icon in the task bar) generally shows that my script is busy running, and doing something. From there it's a simple matter to identify why it's still running.

Since the script is currently busy satisfying a previous request, then a new request can not be initiated.

In my case the problem is some runaway loop that is processing more data than I had expected or it's stuck in some infinite loop.

If you leave the script running while it's stuck, you might also want to open the task manager to see if it's consuming any CPU time or if it's gradually eating more and more memory.